# Fedex API Rate request issues, php

Tags: php, api, fedex

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong I've set the authentication and version number but I just can get authenticated.

I get the following error when I try the sample code.

```
Severity: ERROR
Source: prof
Code: 1000
Message: Authentication Failed
```

Can anyone advise me on this please?! This is the first part of code, which is a barely modified copy of the example.

```
$path_to_wsdl = "./RateService_v18.wsdl";

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$client = new SoapClient($path_to_wsdl, array('trace' => 1)); // Refer to http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ref.soap.php for more information

$request['WebAuthenticationDetail'] = array(
    'UserCredential' =>array(
        'Key' => 'PmzmlFAKEKEYVha', 
        'Password' => 'myfedex-website-password'
    )
); 
$request['ClientDetail'] = array(
    'AccountNumber' => '123456789', 
    'MeterNumber' => '123456789'
);
$request['TransactionDetail'] = array('CustomerTransactionId' => 'testing');
$request['Version'] = array(
    'ServiceId' => 'crs', 
    'Major' => '18', 
    'Intermediate' => '0', 
    'Minor' => '0'
);


$request['ReturnTransitAndCommit'] = true;
$request['RequestedShipment']['DropoffType'] = 'REGULAR_PICKUP'; // valid values REGULAR_PICKUP, REQUEST_COURIER, ...
$request['RequestedShipment']['ShipTimestamp'] = date('c');
$request['RequestedShipment']['ServiceType'] = 'INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY'; // valid values STANDARD_OVERNIGHT, PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT, FEDEX_GROUND, ...
$request['RequestedShipment']['PackagingType'] = 'YOUR_PACKAGING'; // valid values FEDEX_BOX, FEDEX_PAK, FEDEX_TUBE, YOUR_PACKAGING, ...
$request['RequestedShipment']['TotalInsuredValue']=array('Ammount'=>100,'Currency'=>'USD');
$request['RequestedShipment']['Shipper'] = addShipper();
$request['RequestedShipment']['Recipient'] = addRecipient();
$request['RequestedShipment']['ShippingChargesPayment'] = addShippingChargesPayment();
$request['RequestedShipment']['RateRequestTypes'] = 'ACCOUNT'; 
$request['RequestedShipment']['RateRequestTypes'] = 'LIST'; 
$request['RequestedShipment']['PackageCount'] = '1';
$request['RequestedShipment']['RequestedPackageLineItems'] = addPackageLineItem1();
try 
{
    if(setEndpoint('changeEndpoint'))
    {
        $newLocation = $client->__setLocation(setEndpoint('endpoint'));
    }

    $response = $client ->getRates($request);

    if ($response -> HighestSeverity != 'FAILURE' && $response -> HighestSeverity != 'ERROR')
    {   
        $rateReply = $response -> RateReplyDetails;
        echo '<table border="1">';
        echo '<tr><td>Service Type</td><td>Amount</td><td>Delivery Date</td></tr><tr>';
        $serviceType = '<td>'.$rateReply -> ServiceType . '</td>';
        $amount = '<td>$' . number_format($rateReply->RatedShipmentDetails[0]->ShipmentRateDetail->TotalNetCharge->Amount,2,".",",") . '</td>';
        if(array_key_exists('DeliveryTimestamp',$rateReply)){
            $deliveryDate= '<td>' . $rateReply->DeliveryTimestamp . '</td>';
        }else if(array_key_exists('TransitTime',$rateReply)){
            $deliveryDate= '<td>' . $rateReply->TransitTime . '</td>';
        }else {
            $deliveryDate='<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        }
        echo $serviceType . $amount. $deliveryDate;
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</table>';

        printSuccess($client, $response);
    }
    else
    {
        printError($client, $response);
    } 

    writeToLog($client);    // Write to log file   

} catch (SoapFault $exception) {
   printFault($exception, $client);        
}

function addShipper(){
    $shipper = array(
        'Contact' => array(
            'PersonName' => 'Sender Name',
            'CompanyName' => 'Sender Company Name',
            'PhoneNumber' => '9012638716'),
        'Address' => array(
            'StreetLines' => array('Address Line 1'),
            'City' => 'Collierville',
            'StateOrProvinceCode' => 'TN',
            'PostalCode' => '38017',
            'CountryCode' => 'US')
    );
    return $shipper;
}
function addRecipient(){
    $recipient = array(
        'Contact' => array(
            'PersonName' => 'Recipient Name',
            'CompanyName' => 'Company Name',
            'PhoneNumber' => '9012637906'
        ),
        'Address' => array(
            'StreetLines' => array('Address Line 1'),
            'City' => 'Richmond',
            'StateOrProvinceCode' => 'BC',
            'PostalCode' => 'V7C4V4',
            'CountryCode' => 'CA',
            'Residential' => false)
    );
    return $recipient;                                      
}
function addShippingChargesPayment(){
    $shippingChargesPayment = array(
        'PaymentType' => 'SENDER', // valid values RECIPIENT, SENDER and THIRD_PARTY
        'Payor' => array(
            'ResponsibleParty' => array(
            'AccountNumber' => getProperty('billaccount'),
            'CountryCode' => 'US')
        )
    );
    return $shippingChargesPayment;
}
function addLabelSpecification(){
    $labelSpecification = array(
        'LabelFormatType' => 'COMMON2D', // valid values COMMON2D, LABEL_DATA_ONLY
        'ImageType' => 'PDF',  // valid values DPL, EPL2, PDF, ZPLII and PNG
        'LabelStockType' => 'PAPER_7X4.75');
    return $labelSpecification;
}
function addSpecialServices(){
    $specialServices = array(
        'SpecialServiceTypes' => array('COD'),
        'CodDetail' => array(
            'CodCollectionAmount' => array('Currency' => 'USD', 'Amount' => 150),
            'CollectionType' => 'ANY')// ANY, GUARANTEED_FUNDS
    );
    return $specialServices; 
}
function addPackageLineItem1(){
    $packageLineItem = array(
        'SequenceNumber'=>1,
        'GroupPackageCount'=>1,
        'Weight' => array(
            'Value' => 50.0,
            'Units' => 'LB'
        ),
        'Dimensions' => array(
            'Length' => 108,
            'Width' => 5,
            'Height' => 5,
            'Units' => 'IN'
        )
    );
    return $packageLineItem;
}
```

Thank you in advance for ANY help! :)

Comment: Have you entered the correct api key? Account number? Meter number?

Comment: please show more code. you haven't shown where your `$client` executes a call. also- can you show the `binding` WSDL file contents(near the end of the file)

Comment: <binding name="RateServiceSoapBinding" type="ns:RatePortType">
    <s1:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="getRates">
      <s1:operation soapAction="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v18/getRates" style="document"/>
      <input>
        <s1:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <s1:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>

Comment: OMG fedex is the dumb one.. they *just* emailed me a "password" to use...  thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

the password is not your password you already have. it is another one they email you later.  :/